# HTML5 Input Form Reappears after Submit and Hide

Tags: javascript, forms, html, google-chrome

When a user puts in some text into my form and clicks the button, I want to hide the form and show a "thanks" message to the user to let them know I got their text.

By the way, this is for embedding into a Chrome extension pop-up.

Here's what I have:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Extension</title>
    <style>
      body {
        min-width:200px;
        min-height:75px;
        overflow-x:hidden;
      }

      img {
        margin:5px;
        border:2px solid black;
        vertical-align:middle;
        width:75px;
        height:75px;
      }

      .visible{
        display:block;
      }

      .invisible{
        display: none;
      }
    </style>

    <script>
      var PopupController = function () {
          this.button_ = document.getElementById('button');
          this.form_ = document.getElementById('userIdForm');
          this.userId_ = document.getElementsByName('userID')[0];
          this.submitThanks_ = document.getElementById('submitThanks');
          this.addListeners_();
      };

      PopupController.prototype = {
          button_: null,
          form_: null,
          userId_: null,
          submitThanks_: null,

          addListeners_: function () {
              this.button_.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick_.bind(this));
          },

          handleClick_: function () {
              console.log("Submit button clicked");
              var userId = this.userId_.value;

              // Hide the form
              this.form_.classList.add('invisible');
              this.submitThanks_.classList.remove('invisible');
          }
      };

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="window.controller = new PopupController()">
    <h2 class="invisible" id="submitThanks">Thanks!</h2>
    <div id="userIdForm">
      <form>
        <input type="text" name="userID" placeholder="User ID" required/>
        <button id="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the form reappears after the button is clicked. I have noticed that the functionality slightly changes when I put in the required attribute into the input field.

I'm using the latest version of Chrome for Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form is reloading because the page is reloading, try returning false from your submit.

```
<button id="button" type="submit" onclick="return false;">Submit</button>
```

*Edit*

Ah, sorry about that. So the page isn't reloading?

Perhaps try this instead:

```
      handleClick_: function () {
          console.log("Submit button clicked");
          var userId = this.userId_.value;

          // Hide the form
          this.form_.className = "invisible";
          this.submitThanks_.className = "visible";
```

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks. But I tried it and there isn't any change in behavior for me.

Comment: Travis, maybe you have a typo in your answer. I changed it to "return false;" (took out the :) and it worked. Thanks! I'll give you the answer points because you answered first.

Comment: @Miles - Ah, you are correct that was a syntactical mistake on my part, edit now shows the correction.

Answer (score 3):

This is because your button is a "submit" button. So when you click on it, it does its standard behavior, which is to submit the form. It makes an HTTP request and your page is refreshed.
If you don't want this to happen, just change the button type to "button".

Comment: OP stated page wasn't reloading, but I would be curious to see this approach tried as well, changing the button to `<button type="button"`.

Comment: That does work, since the problem was that the form was being submitted and the page was refreshing. It's been a while since I've done manual stuff with forms and I forgot that the page refreshes on form submit. Thanks!

Comment: Glad for you, too bad you marked the other answer as the good one :)